# Birt report how use other locale Parameter?

Tags: java, eclipse, parameters, report, birt

example)

Url work link : localhost:8080/frameset?__report=master.rptdesign&__format=pdf&gubun=02&search=**test**

Url Parameter Not work link : localhost:8080/frameset?__report=master.rptdesign&__format=pdf&gubun=02&search=**검색**

-difference  -> **test : 검색**

---

try 1 : escape(parameter); -> unescape(parameter)

try 2 : parameter isrequired option, input 서

[image]

try 3 : hidden parameter input, but break text ㅁㅁ .. or ??

[image]

I try google search title ...

1. locale bound to a parameter
2. birt report parameter other locale

...

---

I want use parameter locale ko_KR.

but only en_US work...

how do i fix code?

other) birt Version : 4.5

Answer (score 0):

You should URL encode special characters for this kind of URL call.

if you use: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

you can change

```
search=검색
```

to

```
search=%EA%B2%80%EC%83%89
```

perhaps that works. If it does, you should find a proper way to do this programmatically. These kind of errors relate to your character set, not the locale. That should also help in searching for a solution.